# "я цирюльник-с" and "помните-с?" from Anton Chekhov's "В бане"... what is that -c?

Tags: произношение

Love Anton Chekhov. In his story "В бане" a character says:
"— Я, ваше высокородие, не банщик, я цирюльник-с."
"Помните-с? Тогда же вы изволили меня насчет невест расспрашивать."

My question: I'm wondering if anyone can share where the ending -c comes from and the history behind it. Just a lisp or an accent thing?
Thank you!!

Incidentally, I got this from a Russian language channel on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7VG3xLvjkMn5NByEVPyTQg

"В бане" is here: https://youtu.be/uDtkWaoxYJ4

English version: https://youtu.be/9oygnJajgoM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Словоерс**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81)

Словое́рс (тж. словое́р, словое́рик, от традиционных названий букв: С — «слово» и Ъ — «ер») — название частицы -с (написание по старой орфографии — -съ), прибавляемой в русском языке к концу слов в определённых ситуациях:

- в XIX веке — в знак почтения к собеседнику, то есть как адрессивное окончание;
- в конце XIX века к адрессивному значению прибавилось гоноративное, а именно депрециативное (демонстративное самоунижение).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*Словоерс в тексте романа Ф. М. Достоевского «Преступление и наказание» (первое книжное издание, 1867, т. II, с. 121)*

Исходно — сокращение от слова «сударь», «государь». Произносилось, когда было уместно «сударь»: вместо «извольте, сударь» — «извольте-с». Обычное место словоерса — после «да» и «нет» («да-с» и «нет-с»), после глаголов («извольте-с»), а также после любого значимого слова.

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо вам за разъяснение.

Comment: Мерси за "отлично". ))) Нужно ещё кликнуть по нижнему треугольничку в ответе - тогда он рассияется зелёненьким. От щастя. ))))